# Why main is the first thread to get executed in the following code every time i execute the code

Tags: java, multithreading

Every time i am executing the following code,main thread is getting executed first every time,even if i have written the code to print name of main thread below the code to print names of other threads(order of execution).

Here is the code.

```
import java.io.*;
class Thh implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        }
    }
}

class Runth
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        Thh t1=new Thh();
        Thread tt1=new Thread(t1,"thread1");tt1.start();
        Thh t2=new Thh();
        Thread tt2=new Thread(t2,"thread2");tt2.start();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: "Order of execution" - as determined by whom?  It's the OS that decides, not you.

Comment: There is a reason why it called "main"...

Comment: @ duffymo That's only i want to know that why OS is not shuffling the order of execution? Is there a such rule to give priority to main thread?

Comment: If the OS will shuffle the execution order you won't be able to build any program. You won't know what will run first.

Comment: @guy the execution order of tasks, processes and threads is pretty unspecified and non-deterministic ever since, and we're living quite fine with that.

Comment: In order to even start the other threads main() has to execute.  Then it has to block for some reason or use the rest of its time slice or be preempted by a higher priority thread before the OS will look around for another thread to execute.

Comment: @JJF That's right on single-core machines. However, it doesn't need to block or be preempted for another thread to become running if the machine is a multi-core machine.

Comment: If you want that kind of control, you should not write multi-threaded code.  Yours is a profound misunderstanding of what they're for.  I don't know if it's possible to buy a machine these days that has only one core.

Comment: So it is @ChristianHujer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of execution of different Java threads is unspecified and non-deterministic. When I ran your code for the first time, the first three lines were

```
thread1
thread2
main
```

When I ran it for the second time, the lines were

```
main
thread2
thread1
```

This non-determinism and lack of specification is intentional. It provides the implementer of the Java Virtual Machine freedom to use the operating system for thread switching without limiting this to specific operating systems.

Also, on most operating systems, the order of threads is unspecified and non-deterministic. Knowing OS internals can reveal a specific behavior and determinism, however, this is reverse engineered knowledge, and future versions of the OS might change the behavior any time (unless it is official part of the "behavioral contract" of the OS, which for most operating system isn't).

If you need to execute threads in a specified, deterministic way, you need to synchronize them. One way to do that is to make use of `java.lang.Object.wait()` and `java.lang.Object.notify()` in `synchronized` blocks.